Multiple instruction for the same token on Raydium
I need to create a transaction which needs to contain multiple swap instruction on Raydium, not jito or anyting else.
Check this link:
https://solscan.io/tx/2QAYZ2rF8NPNAabSQKbc8HkmC9reyagbzr84eNb6ac3pe2rv7JH7eeyj9QA6jNGoFd3PLx62qxRYqY7srGbKHxrH
As you can see, there are 2 buy/sell instruction in a single transaction, and not used custom Solana contract to swap tokens.
Using typescrip raydium sdk, I could have created swap transaction easily, but I could not added second instruction into the same transaction.
The main difficulty is how can we set exact token amount in the second sell instruction because we can not get exact token amount out from the first buy instruction while it is processed on chain.
What is the solution?
